# Creating database connection in module.php file zf2

Tags: mysql, module, database-connection

I have a onBootstrap method in module.php file. I want to use this function to also store user log details into the mysql db. Not able to use persist and flush methods. Any thoughts, how to create a db connection?

Thanks in advance

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $eventManager->attach('finish', array($this, 'outputCompress'), 100); 

    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();
    $auth = $sm->get('zfcuser_auth_service');      
    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
   // $name = $auth->getresolvedIdentity('id');
    //echo "<pre>"; var_dump($auth); var_dump($routeMatch);
   if($routeMatch && $auth){
        $Userlog = new Userlog();
        $Userlog->setUserid(10);
        $Userlog->setUsername('abc');
        $Userlog->setUrl_loaded('xyz');
        $this->getObjectManager()->persist($Userlog);
        $this->getObjectManager()->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: updated..plz check